# AlarmManager is discarded when application is cleared from background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

This is how I am creating an alarm.
When the app is still running in background the alarm is fired.
but when it is cleared from the recent apps, the alarm is getting discarded. I am registering a new receiver and providing a unique action for differentiation between two alarms. Is there any mistake in my code.

```
        String filter_action = "myPackageName" + request_code_value +"_time";

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(filter_action);

        registerReceiver(new AlarmReciever(), filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(filter_action);
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.get_current_intent_value), request_code_value);
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.alarmtext), alarm_title);
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.alarm_time), newAlarm_Choose_Alarm_Value.getText().toString());

        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, request_code_value, intent, 0);


        calSet.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);

        if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
            // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="com.bigbangpartners.YoWakeUp.activities.AlarmReciever" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="AlarmManager_Start" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are registering and de-registering the `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically in your `Activity`s, then a `BroadcastReceiver` created in this way will remain in existence only as long as the app process is alive. So when you remove your app from the list of recent apps, this `BroadcastReceiver` is also, in effect, destroyed.

On the other hand, a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest is a global, permanent component of an Android app that remains in existence forever, whether the app process is alive or not.

If you want your alarms to be activated even when the app is not in the foreground, then you need to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the app manifest and specify the alarm action as well. You are not doing that, and this, I believe, is the root of your problem.

What you should do:

**1.** Define your `BroadcastReceiver` in manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.bigbangpartners.YoWakeUp.activities.AlarmReciever" >        
</receiver>
```

**2.** Remove all calls to `registerReceiver()` and `unRegisterReceiver()` in your app code as that is not needed.

**3.** Define your alarm `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

Rest of code remains same. First try this and see if it works.

Comment: How to use a broadcast receiver which i registered in manifest. can you please tell me how to set action for it with respect to my code above.

Comment: first I need to understand what you mean by "providing a unique action for differentiation between two alarms" ... this is the reason why you are registering the receiver programmatically, I understand that .... but **WHY** do you need to have a "differentiation between two alarms"" ?

Comment: As I am creating an app where user can create any number of alarms. so I thought I need to differentiate between alarms created by a user. I was thinking that for multiple alarms there need to be different actions in order not to get those overrided.

Comment: hmm .... first lets solve the problem of triggering alarms even if app is gone ... see edited answer

Comment: where have you reached so far ?

Comment: I did the same. and it worked. Thank you so much. :)